# Within htaccess do [or] and pipe act the same?

Tags: .htaccess

In htaccess, are the following conditions exactly the same?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
```

vs

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s) [or]
```

Is the pipe symbol simply a shorter way for using `[or]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the pipe symbol simply a shorter way for using `[or]`

No it is not. pipe (alternation) with no matching text after `|` is provided in `RewriteCond` to always return `true` but `[or]` will attempt to evaluate next `RewriteCond` when `HTTPS` is not `on`.

Comment: So RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)| does not make any sense when it's not followed by anything, correct?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|` does make sense as intent is to always succeed and capture string `s` in `%1`